# How to get emailAddress from Linkedin using allauth in django?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, django-allauth

I want to register users using Linkedin, to retrieve their name, last name and email. For that I'm using allauth on django. I can register the first and last name but I cannot automatically save the email from the data.

Looking in  Home › Social Accounts › Social accounts › "the_user" on Extra data: {"elements": [{"handle": "urn:li:emailAddress:152954186", "handle~": {"emailAddress": "example@example.com"}}], "firstName": { ... . I can see that the code do retrieve the email, but it doesn't store it.

Checking in select  * from auth_user;(from database) or in Home › Authentication and Authorization › Users, I see that the code does not store the email automatically. I suppose that the code retrieve first and last name as those items are not inside Arrays.

My linkedin app has r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile and w_member_social permissions, and I am using OAuth 2.0.

On settings.py :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
]
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
{
'linkedin_oauth2': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'r_liteprofile',
            'r_emailaddress',
            'w_member_social',
        ],
        'PROFILE_FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
            'emailAddress',
            'email-address',
            'profilePicture',
            'public-profile-url',
        ],
        'LOCATION_FIELDS': [
            'location',
        ],
        'POSITION_FIELDS': [
            'company',
        ]
    }
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = 'secret'  # App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET ='secret' #app key
```

and on  register.html

```
{% extends "main/index.html" %}
{% load socialaccount %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p>Datos Registro:</p>
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>

    If you have an account, <a href="login">login</a> instead.

    <br>
    <a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}">Facebook OAuth2</a>
    <a href="{% provider_login_url "linkedin_oauth2" method="oauth2" %}">Linkedin OAuth2</a>
{% endblock %}
```

and on url.py of the app

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

What I want is to the code automaticly store the email item on auth_user.email column . I could do that with a trigger on database but it doesn't feel right to perform that way.

Please help me on successfully store data on a Django way

Comment: Did you try setting `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'` in your settings.py?

Comment: I didn't tried but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't proper check the situation. The email I was trying to store was already registered on **account_emailaddress**, that table has a unique constraint over the email column, so I can not save the same email from other socialaccount_socialaccount (the table to store the registered user from social networks). Removing the entry from account_emailaddress solve that problem.

Right after that I got a ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/linkedin_oauth2/login/callback/ that got solve by coding on settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

as states over there https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1740.

Answer (score 0):

Allauth provides for storing multiple emails for a single user through the `EmailAddress` object, which includes a `verified` field and a `primary` field.  An Allauth `EmailAddress` object that is saved as the primary email will have the email address automatically copied to the `email` field on the [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) (`auth_user` in your case) when the `EmailAddress` object is saved.  Therefore, you could do something like the following:

`from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress`

`email, created = EmailAddress.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, email=`*email_address_from_linked_in*`, verified=True, primary=True)`

```
if not created:
    email.primary = True
    email.save()
```

Again, the key is to set `primary` on`EmailAddress` to be `True` in order to have the email address automatically copied to the `email` field of the [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user).

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems getting the email and fixed it by removing the profile fields all together and setting SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL to True. Now they properly save in the user data

```html
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'linkedin_oauth2': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'r_liteprofile',
            'r_emailaddress',
        ],
        'PROFILE_FIELDS': []
    }
}
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```